# Optimal data structure for a tree where every node has at most 5 childs, but often 1 or 2 used

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory, tree

Now I meet a problem, as I implement a tree in Java, in the following is the code for every node in the data structure．

```
class MLNode {

 private MLNode[] childs;
 public MLNode(int max)
 {

     MLNode[]child=new MLNode[max];
     this.childs=child;

     for (int i = 0; i < childs.length; i++)
     {
         this.childs[i] = null;

     }
 }



 public MLNode[] getChilds()
 {
     return childs;      
 }
 public void setChilds(MLNode[] value)
 {
    childs = value;
 }



}
```

I need a solution optimal both in time and speace but I don't which data structure suits best for me. In the final tree, many nodes contains only one node and also the leaf node has no nodes, I want to save that part of memory. Additionally, I wonder when I calculate the memory I used theoretically, is it 2n or 5n (suppose there exits n nodes in the final tree).

I forget to mention that I need to get a node's child quickly and I use the cooresponding indice to do this. Something like a-child, b-child, ..., and I put a-child in child[0], b-child[1]...

Thank you!

Comment: change array `MLNode[] childs;` to `List<MLNode> childs`, so you don't need init node with `max` value

Comment: @Jerry06 Sorry, I forget to mention that I need to get a node's child quickly and I use the cooresponding indice to do this. Something like a-child, b-child, ..., and I put a-child in child[0], b-child[1]... Thanks

Comment: use `array` `childs[0]` is similar with `List` `childs.get(0)`